# Отобразить программно созданный фрейм

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Нужно создать фрейм, в котором будут изменятся страницы. По заданию его нужно создать программно.
Написал такой код:

```
public static Frame AddFrame;
....
//В конструкторе окна
AddFrame = new Frame();
Grid.SetRow(AddFrame, 6);
Grid.SetColumn(AddFrame, 1);
....
AddFrame.Source = new Uri("PagesForAdd/Choose_HS.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Пробовал смотреть трассировкой, код приведенный выше - исполняется, но нет никакого визуального эффекта.
Но он не отображается при запуске? В чем беда?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вы забыли

```
grid.Children.Add(AddFrame);
```

(И кстати, скорее всего вам не нужен `static`.)